# File movement between Google Shared Drive (team drive) folders using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I am creating a workflow for Shared Drive (Team Drive) where I have 3 folders under team drive:
TO BE APPROVED
APPROVED
REJECTED

I am sending a document from TO BE APPROVED folder for approval, if user approves it then this document should move to APPROVED folder. Same logic for REJECTED.

Now my question is how can I move a document between Shared Drive folders. `DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).addFile()` is not working as I can not have more than one parent in Team Drive.  `DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFile()` is working but it is creating a whole new file with new ID which is not fulfilling my purpose of approval workflow as this is a whole new file.

Is there any way to move file or copy/replace any operations which will not change my file's ID? I tried for REST APIs as well but couldn't found any.

Comment: You must use the Drive REST API to manipulate the parents list directly. It is an advanced service that must be enabled before use.

Comment: Yes @tehhowch, I've updated the answer. I've done it using REST only.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay looks like I found an answer, via REST API I can update file's parents. I've made that call and it's working.

Here's the sample.

```
var apiUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId?addParents=newFolderId&removeParents=oldFolderId&supportsTeamDrives=true";
var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
var header = {"Authorization":"Bearer " + token};
var options = {
"method":"PATCH",
"headers": header
};
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl, options);
```

**UPDATE**
Using Advance Services API we can achieve the same, here's the answer I've received from **Aliaksei Ivaneichyk**

```
function moveFileToFolder(fileId, newFolderId) {  
  var file = Drive.Files.get(fileId, {supportsTeamDrives: true});

  Drive.Files.patch(file, fileId, {
    removeParents: file.parents.map(function(f) { return f.id; }),
    addParents: [newFolderId],
    supportsTeamDrives: true
  });
}
```

Here you need to Enable Drive SDK advance services if you are using Appscript. In case of Appmaker Add Drive SDK as Service in Settings Option.

Comment: Sure!! Appreciate the support.

Comment: In case anyone else finds use for this answer, supportsTeamDrives is deprecated and was replaced with supportsAllDrives. Furthermore, supportsAllDrives will also sunset in June 2020 and team drives will be automatically supported from then on.

Comment: Thanks, so much, @DarpanSanghavi! This is exactly what I needed.