# Is there an API call to move a file from one Team Drive to another?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am looking for a way to move files (also folders) from one Team Drive to another using the API.

Essentially I want to be able to do the "Move to" command in Team Drives from an API call.

I am not seeing an API call that does this explicitly- has anyone come across workarounds? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried the workaround in this [SO post (Google Team Drive Move file between team drive folders using Apps Script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49670353/google-team-drive-move-file-between-team-drive-folders-using-apps-script)?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately this looks like a workaround to move files between folders within the same team drive. I am looking to move from one team drive to another.