# Moving Files in Google Team Drive with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I have a Google Apps Script code for our workplace that is meant to take files uploaded to a single folder, and move them to other folders based on their file name.  This code is working just fine when I try it with my personal Google Drive, but fails when I try it on our workplace Team Drive. Gives the error "API call to drive.files.update failed with error: File Not found:  (line 11)"
Line 11 in this case is the Drive.Files.update line.

Troubleshooting so far: Have ensured that resources > advanced Google Services > Drive API v2 is set to on. Works also when I try it on my personal Google My Drive. Does not work on the workplace Team Drive.  Cannot tell if this is because of some admin restriction on the Team Drive, or I need to use a different Drive.files.update code when in a Team Drive.

```
function moveFiles() {
  var dfldrs=['ALT CHG', 'ALT ADJ', 'ALT PMT', 'APX CHG', 'APX ADJ', 'APX PMT','AUR CHG', 'AUR ADJ', 'AUR PMT','BEA CHG', 'BEA ADJ', 'BEA PMT'];//Seven letter prefixes
  var ofObj={'ALT CHG':'id','ALT ADJ':'id','ALT PMT':'id','APX CHG':'id','APX ADJ':'id','APX PMT':'id-','AUR CHG':'id','AUR ADJ':'id','AUR PMT':'id','BEA CHG':'id','BEA ADJ':'id','BEA PMT':'id'};//distribution folder ids
  var upldFldr=DriveApp.getFolderById('id');
  var files=upldFldr.getFiles();
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file=files.next();
    var key=file.getName().slice(0,7);
    var index=dfldrs.indexOf(key);
    if(index>-1) {
      Drive.Files.update({"parents": [{'id': ofObj[key]}]}, file.getId());  
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: team drive doesn't want you running off with its files. Working as intended. you should be able to COPY them.

Comment: You need to assure Google you know what you're doing wrt Team Drives. Did you read the API guide section on working with Team Drive files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Team Drive Move file between team drive folders using Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49670353/google-team-drive-move-file-between-team-drive-folders-using-apps-script)

Answer (score 0):

The script transfers all your personal files to a shared disk. **Saves the folder structure.**

```
DRIVE_FOLDER_ID = '111aaa'; // Folder ID on the shared drive

function start() {
    var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('"me" in owners');
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();

      // console.info("Old path: ", getFullPath(file));

      newPath = fileMoveWithPath(file, DRIVE_FOLDER_ID);
      if (newPath)
        console.info("New path: ", getFullPath(newPath));
    }
}

function fileMoveWithPath(file, root) {
  var folders = [],
      parent = file.getParents();

  // Проходим по иерархии папок текущего файла до корня
  while (parent.hasNext()) {
    parent = parent.next();
    folders.push(parent);
    parent = parent.getParents();
  }

  if (folders.length > 0)
    targetPath = makeNewPath(folders, DriveApp.getFolderById(root));
  else
    targetPath = DriveApp.getFolderById(root);

  if (targetPath) {
    try {
      targetFile = file.moveTo(targetPath);
    } catch {
      console.error("Error path: ", getFullPath(file));
      return;
    }
    return targetFile;
  };
  return;
}

function makeNewPath(folders, newroot) {
  var f = folders.pop();
  var query = "'" + newroot.getId() + "' in parents and title = '" + f.getName() + "' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' "
  var targetFolder = DriveApp.searchFolders(query);
  if (targetFolder.hasNext()) 
    targetFolder = targetFolder.next()
  else
    targetFolder = newroot.createFolder(f.getName());

  if (folders.length > 0) 
    return makeNewPath(folders, targetFolder)
  else
    return targetFolder;
}

function getFullPath(file) {
  var folders = [],
      parent = file.getParents();
  while (parent.hasNext()) {
    parent = parent.next();
    folders.push(parent.getName());
    parent = parent.getParents();
  }
  if (folders.length) {
    return '> /' + folders.reverse().join("/") + '/' + file.getName();
  }
  return '> /' + file.getName();
}
```